# How to write avi file with OpenCV larger than 2 GB?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm using OpenCV with Python, but actually can switch to C++, so if it's matter please answer question considering it.

I'm writing .avi file(joining multiple avi files into one) using

```
cv2.VideoWriter([filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize[, isColor]])
```

but recently found out that I can't write .avi file larger than 2 GB with it. It even mentioned there: [Due to this OpenCV for video containers supports only the avi extension, its first version. A direct limitation of this is that you cannot save a video file larger than 2 GB.](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html)

But right now I've got no time to learn new library like ffmpeg, I need to do it very fast.

How can I write this file, using C++ or Python with knowledge of OpenCV, or at least with input part - using

```
cv::Mat
```

as frames

Comment: As a quick hack, you can save each frame as an image with a consecutive number, and the use some tool like [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) to make a video with your preferred codec from the image sequence. The image sequence will take a lot of disk space, but you don't need to learn anything new.

Answer (score 3):

This limitation was removed in OpenCV 3.0, due to the introduction of new file formats such as `.mkv`, who do support video files larger than 2GB.

See [Does OpenCV 3.0 Still Has Limits On VideoWriter Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35567585/1011859).

NOTE: The documentation and examples weren't updated yet, so maybe this should be considered experimental.

Answer (score 2):

You have answered your own question but I'm afriad it isn't the answer you want.

From your link

> As you can see things can get really complicated with videos. However, OpenCV is mainly a computer vision library, not a video stream, codec and write one. Therefore, the developers tried to keep this part as simple as possible. Due to this OpenCV for video containers supports only the avi extension, its first version. A direct limitation of this is that you cannot save a video file larger than 2 GB. Furthermore you can only create and expand a single video track inside the container. No audio or other track editing support here. Nevertheless, any video codec present on your system might work. If you encounter some of these limitations you will need to look into more specialized video writing libraries such as FFMpeg or codecs as HuffYUV, CorePNG and LCL.

What this paragraph says is that the developers of OpenCV made a design choice that says you **cannot** write video files larger than 2Gb using OpenCV for the specific reason that it is a computer vision library not a video tool.

Unfortunately if you want to write videos larger than 2Gb you are going to need to learn to use FFMPEG or something similar (It isn't that hard and has good bindings to OpenCV)

Comment: Strange thing is that I just created an uncompressed avi file with OpenCV's VideoWriter, 8 GB. It's a bit weird (ffmpeg finds more frames than what Totem and VLC would play), but the file size doesn't seem to be an issue for me.