# Does OpenCV 3.0 Still Has Limits On VideoWriter Size?

Tags: opencv, video

OpenCV 2.4 `VideoWriter` [couldn't save video files larger than 2GB, since it only accepts .avi files](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html), I am wondering if this is still the case in OpenCV 3.0, or if it can save other kind of video files that doesn't have this limitations.

I tried to find any documentations pointing to a limit of 2GB or a release note saying it's capable to handle larger files, but I can't find none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the [OpenCV 3.0-beta documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html#the-structure-of-a-video) states otherwise, OpenCV 3.0's `VideoWriter` seems to handle other file formats, such as `mkv`, as shown in [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5439).

I adapted the code from the above issue to generate a 4GB `mkv` video (4096 frames of random 2048x2048).

The things to be aware is that the image size should be passed as `width` then `height` in the `VideoWriter` whereas the numpy `array` should be initialized with `height` then `width`. `VideoWriter` will fail silently otherwise.

You will also require a recent OpenCV 3.0 source to handle uncompressed streams.

Comment: They just didn't remove the old documentation, that's the same old text from 2.4 if I recall correctly. My doubt is if right now can I save videos larger than 2Gb or not.

Comment: `6.6G    test_xvid.mkv`, and it looks fine in mplayer (2048x2048 random pixels from numpy)

Comment: Interesting! It's a shame they don't update the examples and the documents... I will have to wait more I guess, my video source isn't squared.

Comment: Hang on, I think it's just a weirdness in the Python bindings. Seems like width and height are swapped. I just need to wait for the beast file to generate to confirm :)

Comment: @mFeinstein: it's actually not a bug, just wrong usage and bad error reporting by `VideoWriter`. Non-square 2>Gb works fine !

Comment: Good to know! But what do you mean by bad usage? Rectangular video does work or not?

Comment: Yes it does work, I (and the people that opened the related issue) missed that VideoWriter swaps `height` and `width`, as indicated in the post.

Answer (score 2):

This is not OpenCV limitation. AVI file size cannot be larger than 2 GB due to format limitations (4-byte size signed integer has max value 2,147,483,647).
 Is it possible to pack video in another container with OpenCV (`mkv` etc)?

[the RIFF header has the following form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318189(v=vs.85).aspx):
'RIFF' fileSize fileType (data)
where 'RIFF' is the literal FOURCC code 'RIFF',
**fileSize is a 4-byte value giving the size of the data in the file**,
and fileType is a FOURCC that identifies the specific file type.

Comment: Yes, I will edit my question to be more clear about it....my point is, OpenCV uses only .avi, and .avi has a limitation of 2GB, so this gives OpenCV a limitation by inheritance... So the question should be if OpenCV 3.0 accepts other formats or still just .avi